# SKAction.playSoundFileNamed works with issue

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I'm using **runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed()** for add sound effect in my game. But Xcode find an issue at this point. When sound is played, screen is lagging. I used **self.runaction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed()**, still it doesn't work. How can I fix this issue? Here is my code :

```
if(nodeTouched == ball){

   runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Tink", waitForCompletion: false))
}
```

Comment: screen is freezing or screen is lagging?

Comment: Screen is freezing about 1 second then it is continue

Comment: ok so it is lagging, writing answer now

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 2):

Create your `SKAction` when you init the class so that the sound file is cached,

```
class MyClass
{
  let tink = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Tink", waitForCompletion: false);

  .....
  if(nodeTouched == ball)
  {

     runAction(tink)
  }
}
```

I would however edit it even further.  Ball should be subclassed, then you can keep your touch code inside your ball, and avoid your if(nodeTouched == ball)

```
class Ball : SKNode
{
  let tink = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Tink", waitForCompletion: false);

  .....
  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
  {

     runAction(tink)
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it. But there is an issue. **runAction(tink, waitForCompletion: false);)** is expected expression. If I didn't add **;** , Xcode says add this **;**

Comment: sorry I thought I took that out

Comment: I used the first approach but it still lags as soon as it plays the first sound.

Comment: @Danny182 This is almost 2 years old,  Apple changed the way they handle audio. I haven't touched the sound library in a while, but a quick work around I can think of is to play the sound on a node that is paused so that it can get put into the cache

Comment: @Danny182 something like `self.run(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run({let node = SKNode();node.isPaused=true;node.run(tink)}),SKAction.wait(forDuration:0.02),SKAction.run({node.removeFromParent})]))`

Comment: This basically creates a new node that adds the sound action, waits about a frame, then removes the node

Comment: @Danny182 did it play sound a frame?

Answer (score 2):

I was having a problem with SKAction.playsoundFileNamed, The code was OK but when I tried to test the game in my iPhone the sound doesn't work. So, I opened the project properties, Build Phases Tab, and in Copy Bundle Resources I added the sound. It worked for me!  [ProjectProperties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiLqV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the current sound folder in Xcode.Open a the sound's file location then create new folder and name it sound or whatever you like then move all the sounds in the newly created folder. Lastly drag and drop the whole folder into Xcode. The point is to put all the sound effect in a folder first then move the whole folder to be add into Xcode. Be sure to check copy items if needed.